# Atomically update multiple related tables

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I am working with SQLite in Android. I have a model object that contains three lists, one of which is a list of lists. So I have five tables: A for the object, B for the list of lists, C for its lists, and D and E for the other two lists. The case that has me stumped is if the user is updating an existing object, and may or may not have made any changes to its lists. I think I will have to query each table B through E for records whose foreign keys match the primary key of the record I'm updating, and then loop through those results to see if I have a matching item in the lists, manually deleting/inserting/updating as necessary. But it seems to me like there should be a better way?

Related questions: If I wrap this whole operation in `beginTransaction()` and `setTransactionSuccessful()`, do I need to do anything else to ensure atomicity? I have never dealt directly with locks in my databases, do I need to add error checking to my existing queries to handle an event in which they are blocked? Is there any error case in which I would need to manually cancel the transaction, or will that occur automatically when I close my database connection?

Comment: You just need to wrap queries in the transaction block (begin / commit parts, which in android translate to the methods you mentioned). You don't have to do any checks yourself. You don't have to worry about locks. If anything goes wrong, you will receive an exception which will contain details about what went wrong. You might hit a deadlock with MySQL (not sure with SQLite but it might be the same), and in case of a deadlock you simply have to repeat the transaction + queries.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on SQLite triggers [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html), This is exactly what you need.

If any error has occurred somewhere after `beginTransaction()`, then try to catch an exception and do not mark this transaction as successful. Without
`setTransactionSuccessful()` call your data wont be affected.

Comment: That looks like it would be very helpful if the data I need to update in tables B through E were duplicated from table A, but in this case the data I need to compare is only in the object I'm trying to save.